# Бескультурие или бескультурье?

Tags: орфография

Я написала "бескультурие", но Ворд меня поправил, предложив "бескультурье". Или допустимы оба варианта?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то Ворд прав, в словарях только одно слово - бескультурье, второй вариант возможен, видимо, только как просторечие.

Comment: Это не просторечие, наоборот, высокий (некогда) стиль.

Comment: Согласна, некогда был высоким, но не в этом случае, культура- латинское заимствование, к высокому "штилю"не относится, а ненормированное словообразование относится всё же к просторечиям, а не к высоким словам.

Comment: Бескультурье - "низкое" слово по смыслу, так что его "стилизовать" под старину бессмысленно.

Comment: Интересно, а почему тогда Вы, не задумываясь, пишете "простореч*ие*"? 
С низким стилем могу согласиться только в том плане, что конкретное слово относительно новое, продукт советских времен, отсюда и отношение к нему соответствующее.

Comment: Потому что это лингвистический термин, который пишется только так, а если б я писала "в просторечье можно сказать так..."(в простом разговоре), можно было бы и с И, и с Ь.Тогда с И было бы более книжным.

Comment: >Любовь. — Не прогневайся на просторечье. Речей,  
— не советовала б пренебречь:  
То летописи огнестрельная речь

Comment: Замечательный пример, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, всегда знал такое объяснение: слова среднего рода пишутся с -ье, если относятся к разговорной речи, а в книжном стиле обычно употребляется -ие (счастье - счастие, раздумье - раздумие). Кроме того, вариант с -ье считается более современным

Comment: Нет, на -ие - это уже не просто книжный, а стилизация под старину. Правда, такое позволяют далеко не все слова, а только особо возвышенные.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы всё-таки написал "отсутствие культуры", извините.